# Запись массива данных в xml

Tags: php, массивы, xml

Беру файлы из папки, считываю из них данные в массив `$result` и записываю в текстовой файл `config.txt`.

```
$dir = opendir('uploads');

while($file = readdir($dir)){

$content = file ('uploads/'.$file);


$some_word = "Имя узла";
$some_word2 = "Зарегистрированный владелец";
$some_word3 = "Модель системы";
$some_word4 = "Полный объем физической памяти";
$some_word5 = "Домен";

 echo '<p style="color:red;">'.basename($file).'</p>';

foreach ($content as $line) { // читаем построчно
    $result = explode (':', $line, 2); // разбиваем строку и записываем в массив
    // проверка на совпадение
    if (($result[0] == $some_word) || ($result[0] == $some_word2) || ($result[0] == $some_word3) || ($result[0] == $some_word4) || ($result[0] == $some_word5)) {    

         echo '<b>'.$result[0].':</b> '.$result[1].'<br>';
         file_put_contents('config.txt', $result, FILE_APPEND);
    }       
}

}

?>
```

Вот дамп массива одного файла:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "Имя узла" [1]=> string(37) " OLGABUZOVA " } array(2) { [0]=> string(53) "Зарегистрированный владелец" [1]=> string(16) " Rumyashi " }  array(2) { [0]=> string(27) "Модель системы" [1]=> string(31) " P67-DS3-B3 " } array(2) { [0]=> string(57) "Полный объем физической памяти" [1]=> string(16) " 8 175 МБ " }  array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "Домен" [1]=> string(37) " RORSHAH " }
```

То есть, как я понимаю для каждой строки отдельный массив.
В какой вид нужно привести данные, чтобы я смог сгенерировать xml файл вида

```
<file1> 
<char1>PAVELDUROV</char1> 
<char2>VK</char2> 
<char3>P67-DS3-B3</char3> 
<char4>4 893 МБ</char4> 
<char5>LONDON</char5> 
</file1>

<file2>
<char1></char1>
<char2></char2> 
<char3></char3> 
<char4></char4> 
<char5></char5> 
</file2>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать `SimpleXMLElement()` для чтения xml файла, но дефакто их нужно хранить не в `.txt` а в `.xml` файле http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<files>
    <file> 
    <char1>PAVELDUROV</char1> 
    <char2>VK</char2> 
    <char3>P67-DS3-B3</char3> 
    <char4>4 893 МБ</char4> 
    <char5>LONDON</char5> 
    </file>
    <file>
    <char1></char1>
    <char2></char2> 
    <char3></char3> 
    <char4></char4> 
    <char5></char5> 
    </file>
</files>
```

Можно вот так:

```
// функция для записи файла. Переменная $file это абсолютный адрес к файлу
    public static function write_file($file, $content)
    {
    $my_file = fopen($file, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($my_file,  $content);
    fclose($my_file);
    }

$xml_content = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
$xi=0;
for(;;){

// если нет доступа к следующему элементу, то выходим из цикла
if(!isset($xml_content->file[$xi]))break;

// обрабатывает каждый элемент file командой plot, в этом месте нужно поиграться в зависимости от того как вы хотите записывать в файл, php.net рекомендует использовать SimpleXML, ну а функция для записи файла уже проверена временем :)
write_file($file_address,$xml_content->file[$xi]->plot);
$xi++;
}
```

Чтобы забрать данные из `<char1>`

```
$xml_content->file[$xi]->char1->plot
```